# Google AdMob Code Issue (Running Live Mode ?!)

Tags: android, mobile, admob, ads

I signed up for Google AdMob services recently and been using this code to create the AdRequest.

```
private AdRequest createAdRequest()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
        .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
            .AddKeyword("game")
            .SetGender(Gender.Male)
            .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
            .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
            .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
            .Build();

}
```

When logging in today morning, I saw some impression (around 100) created obviously by myself. The TestDevice ID is of course not the correct ID because I was too lazy to find out the correct one.
Are the ads showing right now in my app "real" ads? Can I fix this by adding the correct device ID and will I see then inside App that the Ads are just "Demo"?
... Is there no "general testing-mode" ? I'm developing together with a friend and he has of course a different device ID...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple device IDs, no problem:

```
 .AddTestDevice("YOURDEVICEIDYOURDEVICEIDYOURDEVICEID")
 .AddTestDevice("FRIENDSDEVICEIDFRIENDSDEVICEIDFRIEND")
 .AddTestDevice("SOMEONEELSESOMEONEELSESOMEONEELSESOM")
```

Now your friends and you will see demo ads, all the rest will see real ads.

To get the device id you can start your app and check the logcat for an admob log that looks more or less like this:

`05-20 20:27:20.888: I/Ads(32367): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("BANANANAANANANANANANNANANANANANA") to get test ads on this device.`

Just use this id as a parameter in the addTestDevice method then. See also this [related admob question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30357680/2399024)