# why admob doesn't appear while testing ? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, admob

Help me guy's i know there are lot's of question like that but no one is worked for me . I have three tabs with three fragment each fragment contain a listview
I want to put AdMob at the bottom of each list view but add doesn't appear at the emulator.

Here is my code .

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="androidthirst.company.abhi.totalenglish.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        <include layout="@layout/content_tab_layout_demo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView1"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/band">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code of 
ActivityMain.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RateItDialogFragment.show(this,getFragmentManager());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-8835951437809468~5344380934");

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("3FB54EBF85D756B8").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.getMenu();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TabLayout tabLayout =(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("GRAMMAR"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TENSE"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("SPOKEN ENGLISH"));
```

please help me to shortout this issue

And that's the image of my application 
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2lpt.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Admob needs Google Play Services installed on device.
make sure google play services installed on emulator.

Comment: Thank's sir , How can i check that? I am using Genymotion

Comment: you are using genymotion, and in genymotion google play services are not installed by default. you need to install (flash).

Comment: If i want to check on real device ? Is there any problem with code or not?

Comment: `AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();` this will may create problem. but you can try.

Comment: Doesn't work I think i had problem with my code can you please sort out .

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULAT‌​OR)`

add `.addTestDevice("YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID")`

as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355041/difference-between-device-id-emulator-and-test-emulator-when-testing-admob-on-mo).